# Is there a way to print interpolated shell commands while preserving redirections?

Tags: shell, debugging, io-redirection

Suppose I have the following shell program.

```
#!/bin/sh
FOO="foo"
echo $FOO | cat
```

I want to generate another shell program that does the same thing as this one, except that all shell variables have been substituted.  For example,

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "foo" | cat
```

I know that I can get close if I run the above program using `#!/bin/sh -x`, but that output does not preserve redirections.  Instead, I get

```
+ FOO=foo
+ echo foo
+ cat
foo
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following shell:

```
$ cat eval.sh 
echo "#!/bin/sh"
FOO="foo"
echo "echo $FOO | cat"
```

will write a shell:

```
$ sh eval.sh 
#!/bin/sh
echo foo | cat
```

which does what you need.